# Combine an object parameter with array values in Highcharts reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, highcharts

Sorry don't know how to exactly search this since English is not my first language. What I want do is combine array values to an object parameter. I am using highcharts reduce method to show the occurrences of a word My object is `obj{}`

```
var data = Highcharts.reduce(series, function(arr, word) {
  var obj = Highcharts.find(arr, function(obj) {
    return obj.name === word;
  });
  obj = {
    name: word,
    weight: sortWeight()
  };
  arr.push(obj);
  console.log(obj);
  return arr;
}, []);
```

The sortWeight function is a just a for loop

```
function sortWeight() {
            for (var i =0; i < sortedWeights.length; i++) {
                return sortedWeights [i];
            }
 }
```

The problem I am facing is the answer I always get using this strategy is only the first element of the array.
So the sorted Weights array is something like `sortedWeights =  [28, 17, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6]` but my Object`obj` always has weight of 28 the first value of the array. How can I change the value of weight so the second word has value 17 third 15 and so on. The series array is like `["great", "friendly", "good", "beautiful", "nice", "wonderful", "clean", "excellent", "helpful", "the best", "better", "comfortable", "front desk", "amazing", "perfect", "awesome", "amenities", "complaint", "gorgeous", "definitely stay"]` Now the answer I want to get i.e data array `[{name:great, weight:28}, {name:friendly, weight:17}, {name:good, weight:15}, {name:beautiful, weight:15}....]`

Comment: `sortWeight()` always returns the 1s item (28), and exits the loop.

Comment: @OriDrori Yes I know that, but will be your suggestion for the fix?

Comment: Add the relevant missing data (`series`), and what should be the end result.

Comment: @OriDrori Edited the question. The result is at the end is what I want to achieve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the `series` with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and use the index (`i`) to get the matching number from `sortedWeights`:

```js
var series = ["great", "friendly", "good", "beautiful", "nice", "wonderful", "clean", "excellent", "helpful", "the best", "better", "comfortable", "front desk", "amazing", "perfect", "awesome", "amenities", "complaint", "gorgeous", "definitely stay"];
var sortedWeights =  [28, 17, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6];

var result = series.map(function(word, i) {
  return {
    name: word,
    weight: sortedWeights[i]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```